# while loop - will not work if $i = 0

Tags: php

```
$i = 1;

while ( $i++ )
{
    echo $i;

    if ( isset( $_POST["item_name$i"] ) )
    {
        //do something
    }
    else break;
}
```

This will output - 2,3

if I set $i = 0 I get nothing, I want 1,2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip purrfection, but I understand that it increments it, thing is that I want $i = 0 so it will be 1,2 - but it will die before it hits the increment phase

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is pre-increment not post-increment

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while(++$i){
echo $i;
    if (isset($_POST["item_name$i"])){
        //do something;
    }
else break;
}
?>
```

Pre-increment increments the number first then echos it to you
Post-increment echos it to you then increments it

Comment: Thanks This worked, if anyone sees this give me a bump cause some people are giving me negatives, it was a legit question

Comment: If it worked then choosing it as a correct answer is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$i = 1;
    while (++$i){
    echo $i;
if (isset($_POST["item_name$i"])){
 do something
}
else {break;}
    }
```